# Array in Node.js, how to work with it

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm a newbye in web programming and even more in Javascript, but I'm trying to learn it as I learn Node.js, and I found this strange error... I've got this code:

```
var structobject = function(type, title, isReplicable, isVisible) {
    this._type = type;
    this._title = title;
    this._childElements = new Array();
    this._isReplicable = isReplicable;
    this._id = 0;  //TODO
};

structobject.prototype.addChild = function (element) {
    structobject._childElements.push(element);
};

structobject.prototype.stringify = function () {
    console.log("Main element: "+this._title);
    for (var i=0;i<this._childElements.length;i++) {
        console.log("Child "+i+": "+this._childElements[i]._title);
    }
};

structo1 = new structobject(1, "element1", true, true);
structo1.addChild(new structobject(2, "element2", true, true));
structo1.stringify();
```

I've got a problem here... as you may see, `_childElements` is intended to be an array, and I've got the function `addchild` which should add a child element into it.

The rest of the code works, but this gives me the following error:

```
C:\Zerok\DevCenter\Structify\public_html\js\object.js:22
  structobject._childElements.push(element);
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Why does it say childElements is not defined? I tried not defining the variable, and also tried equaling it to `this._childElements = [];` but none of these ways seem to work either.

What should I do so I can work dynamically with this array?

Answer (score 5):

```
structobject._childElements.push(element);
```

You're trying to modify the (non-existent) `_childElements` property of the **Constructor function** instead of the **instance** you created with `new structobject`.

Use `this` instead of `structobject` on that line.

---

It is conventional, in JavaScript, to use variables starting with capital letters for constructor functions.

```
var structobject = function(...) {
```

would be better written as:

```
var Structobject = function(...) {
```

or (since it is a constructor that makes objects):

```
var Struct = function(...) {
```

or (because named functions are easier to deal with in debuggers):

```
function Struct (...) {
```

Comment: It worked! I see now it was a silly fail, thank you for the fix. Also, the convention tips are nice, I think I'm adding them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of structobject